# Busqueda especifica de etiqueta

Tags: wordpress

Tengo varias entradas con varias etiquetas (diferentes), algunas de ellas, en la parte iniciar tienen la misma numeriación (026...).

Deseo que al realizar una búsqueda  "026", no me salgan todas las entradas con el inicio de esa etiqueta.

Como podría resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

ENCONTRE LA SOLUCIÓN

Solo deben agregar en **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_is_exact', 10 );

function my_search_is_exact( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'exact', true );
    }
}
```